# sql substitute name_id with names from another table

Tags: sql, substitution

I have three tables:

```
match:
id, team1_id, team2_id, tournament_id
333, 4772, 4708, 4508

teams:
id, name
4772, Wolves
4708, Bolton

tour:
id, name
4508, Premier League
```

I would like to do this as a query from match - where team1_id, team2_id, tournament_id are substituted with the values from table teams and tour.

`example: "select * from match where id=333"` should result in:

```
333, Wolves, Bolton, Premier League
```

Also the tables have tens of thousands rows..

Comment: You need to JOIN teams twice (once for each team), and also JOIN tour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from match m 
inner join teams t on m.team1_id=t.id 
inner join teams s on m.team2_id=s.id 
inner join tour o on o.id = m.tournament_id 
where m.id=333
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped me alot. This seems to work: 

select * 
from match m
inner join teams t on m.team1_id=t.id 
inner join teams s on m.team2_id=s.id 
inner join tour o on o.id = m.tournament_id
where m.id=333

Comment: @whydoesitnotwork:- You are welcome! you can accept the answer if that helped you. A right tick mark turns green when clicked

Answer (score 0):

Try using a query

```
select m.id, t1.name, t2.name,t3.name 
from match m inner join teams t1 on m.team1_id=t1.id 
inner join teams t2 on m.team2_id=t2.id 
inner join m.tournament_id=t3.id
```